# WebRtc SDK for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, sdk, video-streaming, webrtc

I've been Searching various iOS and Android SDKs all week that have the ability to live stream video in real time (with low latency) and have run into many problems. Usually the example projects they provide don't work.. Then the ones that do are quit expensive... Then the ones that I do find that work don't offer one-to-many option. The support from the companies I've talked to is awful and SLOW

All that I'm needing for my project is to integrate one-to-many live video streaming (similar to Periscope).

Does anyone know of a quicker and easier way to accomplish this? Has anyone else run into these problems? The functionality I need would be similar to periscope. I appreciate any help or guidance on the topic as I'm tearing my hair out reviewing all of these supposed 'solutions'

Thanks

Comment: ooVoo was the only SDK we could get to operate properly and it has limitations on the number viewers. It also charges you per minute for each viewer..... We also tried Red5, Skylink.io, Opentok/Tokbox, Bit6, and some others.... None of their example builds compiled properly or were perhaps overly complicated. I'm learning more about the technology but still have no real solution

Comment: on iOS I'm using [cordova-plugin-iosrtc](https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc) but it is a Cordova plugin, not a native SDK for iOS

Comment: hello, which one is working? I'd need a simple one working example since many are not